# Paste text into Google Sheets along with instruction to format it

Tags: google-sheets

The content in notepad is like this

Line 1

Line 2

Line 3 - Bold me

Line 4 - Change my color to Red

Line 5 - Underline me

What can I add along with Line 3, 4, and 5 so that it looks like below after pasting text into Google Sheets?
[image]

Comment: @Marios I have text in notepad and I paste it into Google sheets, each line will appear as a separate cell. Then I manually format the pasted text. I am wondering if somehow it is possible to append formatting information along with each line so that they appear formatted as expected. Can GAS solve the problem? Thanks

Comment: you can use conditional formatting in google sheets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You can use [RichTextValueBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/rich-text-value-builder)

You would need to use some kind of conditional statement, e.g. "If text contains the substring 'Underline me', pass to the `RichTextValueBuilder` the text style `underlineStyle`".

Sample snipet:

```js
var myText = "...";
var richValue;
var myStyle;
const underlineStyle = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle().setUnderline(true).build();
const boldStyle = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle().setBold(true).build();
if(myText.indexOf("Underline me") != 0){
  myStyle = underlineStyle;
} else if (myText.indexOf("Bold me") != 0){
  myStyle = boldStyle;
} else {return myText}
myText = myText.split("-")[0];
var endOffset = myText.length-1;
richValue = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue()
  .setText(myText)
  .setTextStyle(0, endOffset, myStyle)
  .build();
return richValue;
```

If you want to be able to apply more than one formatting style to your text, you code will get respectively more complex.

Comment: This snippet gives enough to solve the problem. Than you